# User cannot accept my answer

Tags: discussion

A user thanked me for my help but told me that he(/she) cannot accept [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14897570) because he doesn't have enough reputation for that.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. That is not possible. Any author of a question can accept an answer 15 minutes after asking the question.

Comment: Okay. Then what am I supposed to do? I would get my points... ;)

Comment: @Bart [the asker's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896783/how-to-deal-with-arrays-in-java/14897570#comment20894416_14897570) suggests to me they might be q-banned; would that stop them accepting?

Comment: Nothing much. Accepting answers is up to the OP. They should not be pushed into accepting anything. You could link them [to this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) just to inform them, but that's about it. Don't push anyone into accepting anything. (Note: I have left a comment for the OP of the particular question).

Comment: @AakashM No, not that I know of.

Comment: @qben The asker may not be able to upvote, if they don't have enough rep, but they can accept the answer.  They may not realize there's a difference between those two concepts.  That said, you should not be overly concerned with getting your answers accepted.  Badgering the OP to accept your question is frowned upon, and will most likely have very negative consequences.  If it seems that the OP doesn't know *how* to accept an answer, as said earlier, the most you should really do is link them to the FAQ post explaining *how* to do so.  That's the most you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Even question-banned users can edit/accept on their questions.

Hey may have clicked the upvote button instead. Especially if he's on mobile; it's very common to mis-tap on mobile.

Checking out [the actual comment being discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896783/how-to-deal-with-arrays-in-java/14897570#comment20894416_14897570), it looks like the OP doesn't *want* to accept, since he got a bad "reputation" (not the EXP stuff, the "what others think of you" stuff) for asking it.

Comment: But [the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1813163/user1813163) does have more than 15 rep.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: so? I'm saying that it's not possible for the OP to be unable to accept. Rep doesn't come into the picture.

Comment: I mean that if he clicked the upvote button by mistake, he didn't get any error that might have caused him to say what he said. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: He has 15 rep now. He didn't have it at the time of the comment :)

Answer (score 4):

You've misinterpreted the OP's comment. To clarify, [the OP said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896783/how-to-deal-with-arrays-in-java/14897570#comment20894416_14897570):

> sorry, You know, I can't do it. I got too bad reputation because of
>   this question ;(

This means the negative reaction to their question makes them unwilling to accept an answer, not that they are technically unable to accept an answer.

Comment: Very interesting answer. In fact, this point of view didn't come to my mind.